# How to change colormatrix x,y coordinate of image?

Tags: android, imageview, colormatrix

I am developing an app which allows users to color the images. I have the color matrix of the color I want to apply but the problem is instead of changing color of x y coordinates whole image gets colored. I don't know how to apply the colormatix to specified coordinates of the image.

I am using

```
matrix = 
    new float[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, };

imageview.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix));
```

I am looking for something like `imageview.SetPixelColorMatrix(x,y,matrix)`

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use
createBitmap (Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height, Matrix m, boolean filter)
here you can specify the co-ordinates of the source.for further details see [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.html).